# Attach data in MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate in csv format in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented send mail functionality using MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate.
But i want to send data in csv format.I don't know how it possible.
Can you give me idea about that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303011/how-to-add-vcf-file-as-attachment-in-application-iphone) can help.

The mime should be "text/plain".