# how to add .vcf file as attachment in application iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, attachment, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, vcf-vcard

In my app I want to add .vcf file as attachment in MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: how to make a vcf file in iphone for all contact pls help me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) shows that its **addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:** instance method is the way to go:

```
- (void)addAttachmentData:(NSData*)attachment mimeType:(NSString*)mimeType fileName:(NSString*)filename
```

The *attachment* is the actual vcf file loaded or transformed into NSData.

The *mimeType* for a vcf is **@"text/x-vcard"**.

The *fileName* is whatever you want to call it, though you should uses the .vcf extension to ensure that email programs will understand it.

Comment: how to make a vcf file in iphone for all contact pls help me .

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code to create a vcf file and save it in directory.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

//-------------------Creating and saving vcf --------------------------------
CFArrayRef contacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFDataRef vcards = (CFDataRef)ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople(contacts);
NSString *vcardString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)vcards encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *folderPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.vcf"];
[vcardString writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@",[fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: folderPath error:&error]);
if (addressBook) {
    CFRelease(addressBook);
}
```